# Parse FOR loop using ANTLR based PLSQL parser

Tags: sql, parsing, antlr, antlr3, sql-parser

I have modified the PLSQL parser given by [Porcelli] (https://github.com/porcelli/plsql-parser ). I am using this parser to parse PlSql files. I am facing issue with parsing FOR loop statements, e.g.

```
for i in 1..l_line_tbl.count
LOOP
l_line_tbl(i).schedule_ship_date := l_max_ship_date;
l_line_tbl(i).ship_set_id := x_ship_set_id;
END LOOP;
```

Above statement is not parsing and its throwing EarlyExitException.

Now, if I modify this statement and put a space between 1 and double dot (..) , it will parse the statement. I am not sure how to handle first case.

```
for i in 1 ..l_line_tbl.count
LOOP
l_line_tbl(i).schedule_ship_date := l_max_ship_date;
l_line_tbl(i).ship_set_id := x_ship_set_id;
END LOOP;
```

Parser Grammar:

```
loop_statement
@init    {    int mode = 0;    } 
:    label_name?
    (while_key condition {mode = 1;} | for_key cursor_loop_param {mode = 2;})?
    loop_key
    seq_of_statements
    end_key loop_key label_name?
    -> {mode == 1}? ^(WHILE_LOOP[$while_key.start] label_name* 
    ^(LOGIC_EXPR condition) seq_of_statements)
    -> {mode == 2}? ^(FOR_LOOP[$for_key.start] label_name* cursor_loop_param seq_of_statements)
    -> ^(loop_key label_name* seq_of_statements)
;

// $<Loop - Specific Clause

cursor_loop_param
@init    {    int mode = 0;    }
:    (index_name in_key reverse_key? lower_bound DOUBLE_PERIOD)=> 
        index_name in_key reverse_key? lower_bound DOUBLE_PERIOD upper_bound
    -> ^(INDEXED_FOR index_name reverse_key? ^(SIMPLE_BOUND lower_bound upper_bound))
|     record_name in_key ( cursor_name expression_list? {mode = 1;} | LEFT_PAREN 
select_statement RIGHT_PAREN)
    ->{mode == 1}? ^(CURSOR_BASED_FOR record_name cursor_name expression_list?)
    -> ^(SELECT_BASED_FOR record_name select_statement)
;
```

// $>

Lexer Grammar:

```
FOR_NOTATION
:    UNSIGNED_INTEGER
    {state.type = UNSIGNED_INTEGER; emit(); advanceInput();}
    '..'
    {state.type = DOUBLE_PERIOD; emit(); advanceInput();}
    UNSIGNED_INTEGER
    {state.type = UNSIGNED_INTEGER; emit(); advanceInput(); $channel=HIDDEN;}
;

fragment
UNSIGNED_INTEGER
:    ('0'..'9')+ 
;
```

Comment: Show the relevant part of the grammar.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError - added grammar.

Comment: do you have the whole grammar somewhere?

Comment: did you try no-AST version of the grammar? That one works for me

Comment: @ibre5041 - i have shared the github link. Full grammar is present there.

Comment: @ibre5041 - Can you tell me which version works for you? If it is present in the link tht i have shared, can u point tht out? thanks.

Comment: The grammar has two versions AST and no-AST one. I recall I probably fixed this issue some time ago. Try to use mine branch. Just note this one was ported to ANTLR3.5. See https://github.com/ibre5041/plsql-parser

Comment: ok I have it: https://github.com/ibre5041/plsql-parser/commit/93a12a12d107d8b3b789b42f9bfbe6f55a8ecbf8

Comment: Thanks @ibre5041, i changed lexer grammar for FOR_NOTATION and it works :)